# Combine a set of "ranges" to find least number of ranges - how to improve it?

Tags: java

Given a set of ranges with lower bound and upper bound, I need to combine these ranges to produce minimum number of ranges which will cover all the values in the original set and nothing else.

```
Ex 1: input  [100, 200], [120-170],[210 - 230]. Ouput - [100-200], [210-230]
Ex 2: input [100, 200], [120-210],[210 - 230]. Ouput - [100-230]
```

Comment: "How to improve it" questions generally go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @HyperZ - I'm not required to keep the original tuple as is. I need to combine them to arrive at least number of tuples that will have every possible value in the original range covered and nothing else.

Comment: @HyperZ.. no. For the first example, [100-230] is incorrect because it covers values 201-209 which are not covered in the original input

Comment: @RKodakandla Ok my bad then. Maybe you should edit to clarify this. :)

Comment: Shouldn't have the output for Ex 1 not change? or end up like [100], [120 - 170], [200], [210 - 203]?  and Ex2 have an output of [100], [120 - 230]?

Comment: @RKodakandla Do you want the code or algorithm?

Comment: @Sumeet.. I just wanted to verify if the code I have is good enough or it can be improved. I wanted to delete the question but I couldn't because there are answers associated. So I just edited the question to remove all of my code. I removed it because I was going to submit it for my assignment :).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

You've used the most efficient algorithm that involves O(n logn) sorting before the O(n) merge). So no, I don't think there's any additional improvements you can make.